# Display buffer name in `header-line`, but non-truncated

Tags: header-line

I use a header line to display the buffer file name, but I don't want it to truncate the name.

I don't want to display it in my mode-line, because I already have too much information there.

The problem is that I often split the window and I need to at all times to see the name of the buffer.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. But maybe `(global-)tab-line-mode` or `tab-bar-mode` can help you out?

Comment: You can set `frame-title-format` to define what is shown in the title bar. You can use `%f` to display the whole filename including path, or `%b` for the while filename without  the path.

Comment: @rsp: OP asked about the header line, not the frame title.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```lisp
(setq header-line-format '("%e" mode-line-buffer-identification))
```

or this, if you *do* want to limit the number of chars by truncating the buffer name to, say the first 7 chars:

```lisp
(setq header-line-format '("%e" (-7 . mode-line-buffer-identification)))
```

The variable `mode-line-buffer-identification` displays the current buffer name, and the `-7` means show only the first 7 chars of that name.

---

On the other hand, you mentioned the `buffer-file-name`.  In that case, you can use something like this:

```lisp
(setq header-line-format '("%f"))
```

or this, if you *do* want to truncate the name to, say, the first 13 chars:

```lisp
(setq header-line-format '((-13 "%f")))
```

or this, if you don't want the directory part of the file name, and you do want to limit the name to, say, the first 13 chars:

```lisp
(setq header-line-format
      '(:eval (list -13 (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)))))
```